# Value is always same when try to update data from table

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two tables that are connected, `Wallets` and `Transaction`. Now, Each transaction is connected with wallet and this are entites:

`Wallets:`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wallet")
public class Wallet {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "wallet_id")
private Long id;

@NotBlank(message = "Please, insert a wallet name")
private String walletName;

@NotNull(message = "Please, insert a amount")
private Double initialBalance;

@Transient
private double totalBalance;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnore
private User user;

@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private Long userId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "wallet", cascade = {
        CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<Transaction> transactions;
```

`Transactions:`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction")
public class Transaction {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "transaction_id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private Long userId;

@Column(name = "wallet_name", nullable = false)
private String walletName;

@NotNull(message = "Please, insert a amount")
@Min(value = 0, message = "Please, insert a positive amount")
private Double amount;

private String note;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column(name = "date")
private LocalDate date;

@ManyToOne
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.NO_ACTION)
@JoinColumn(name = "wallet_id", nullable = false)
private Wallet wallet;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "transaction_type", columnDefinition = "ENUM('EXPENSE', 'INCOME')")
private TransactionType transactionType;

@Nullable
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "expense_categories", columnDefinition = "ENUM('FOOD_AND_DRINK', 'SHOPPING', 'TRANSPORT', 'HOME'," +
        " 'BILLS_AND_FEES', 'ENTERTAINMENT', 'CAR', 'TRAVEL', 'FAMILY_AND_PERSONAL', 'HEALTHCARE'," +
        " 'EDUCATION', 'GROCERIES', 'GIFTS', 'BEAUTY', 'WORK', 'SPORTS_AND_HOBBIES', 'OTHER')")
private ExpenseCategories expenseCategories;

@Nullable
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "income_categories", columnDefinition = "ENUM('SALARY', 'BUSINESS', 'GIFTS', 'EXTRA_INCOME', 'LOAN', 'PARENTAL_LEAVE', 'INSURANCE_PAYOUT', 'OTHER')")
private IncomeCategories incomeCategories;
```

This is service to update table:

```
@Override
public void updateIncome(Transaction transaction, Long transactionId) {
    transaction = getTransactionById(transactionId);
    double amount = transaction.getAmount();
    System.out.println(transaction.getAmount());
    transaction.getWallet().setInitialBalance(transaction.getWallet().getInitialBalance() + amount);
    this.transactionRepository.save(transaction);
}
```

This is `controller:`

```
  @PostMapping("/updateIncome/{transactionId}")
public String updateIncome(@PathVariable(value = "transactionId") long transactionId, @Valid Transaction transaction, BindingResult result, Model model) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    long userId = user.getId();

    transaction = transactionService.getTransactionById(transactionId);

    boolean thereAreErrors = result.hasErrors();
    if (thereAreErrors) {
        model.addAttribute("incomeCategories", IncomeCategories.values());
        return "income_transaction";
    }

    transactionService.updateIncome(transaction, transactionId);
    return "redirect:/api/wallet/userWallet/balance/" + userId;
}
```

And what is the problem?

You see here:

```
 double amount = transaction.getAmount();
 System.out.println(transaction.getAmount());
```

That is now `1` because initally transaction is created and amount is set to `1`, but when I open the page and change amount field to `15` for example so I'm actually updating it there, and submit form its still `1` and here `transaction.getWallet().setInitialBalance(transaction.getWallet().getInitialBalance() + amount);` is also `+ 1 (1 as amount)` instead of `15` as a new value because I'm updating it.

What Im doing wrong? I'm trying to update transaction data by Id that is related to wallet but have trouble

Comment: Do you use the value returned by save()?

Comment: Ughh, I'm not sure that I understand what you excalty mean, If you dont mind, be more specific, sorry

Comment: It looks like you’re overwriting the transaction with the one in the database before you call the method to update `transaction = transactionService.getTransactionById(transactionId);`

Comment: When I remove that line result is same

Comment: Also, just to mention, you can see that In transaction table I have field as `note` and when i try to edit that field its also as for `amount`, new values are not recieved

Comment: You’re doing the same thing in both controller and service. You take in the `Transaction` object, but then overwrite it when you fetch the existing from the database. I suggest making a new object such as `Transaction existing = transactionService.getTransactionById(transactionId);`, then overwrite it’s data with the new fields from `transaction` and call `save(existing);`

Comment: Both `amount` and `note` are not annotated as `@Column`

Comment: @CalvinP. Can you be a bit more specific? Like where I need to create new `existing` object? In controller?

Comment: @Frosty I would recommend creating it in the service actually, as traditionally this is where most of your business logic should lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> transaction = transactionService.getTransactionById(transactionId);

The problem is in the above as you reused the variable. The incoming new `transaction` with value 15 is getting overwritten by an already existing `transaction` with initialValue 1;

The following should work now:

```
@PostMapping("/updateIncome/{transactionId}")
public String updateIncome(@PathVariable(value = "transactionId") long transactionId, @Valid Transaction transaction, BindingResult result, Model model) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    long userId = user.getId();

    boolean thereAreErrors = result.hasErrors();
    if (thereAreErrors) {
        model.addAttribute("incomeCategories", IncomeCategories.values());
        return "income_transaction";
    }

    transactionService.updateIncome(transaction, transactionId);
    return "redirect:/api/wallet/userWallet/balance/" + userId;
}


@Override
public void updateIncome(Transaction transaction, Long transactionId) {
    Transaction existingTransactionInDb = getTransactionById(transactionId);
    double amount = transaction.getAmount();
    System.out.println(transaction.getAmount());
    existingTransactionInDb.getWallet().setInitialBalance(existingTransactionInDb.getWallet().getInitialBalance() + amount);
    this.transactionRepository.save(existingTransactionInDb);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is fine, I tried like you but its look like I missed something. By the way, I mentioined above that I also have a `note` column inside transaction table, but when I update it its not changed, look like same problem like for amount before

Comment: Hi, I made it, I just have one question regardles amount field, if you have a time to give me advice about it

Comment: To solve the `note` problem update the `transaction` variable and save the `transaction` variable instead of `existingTransactionInDb`. Also, don't forget to check if `transaction` and `existingTransactionInDb` primaryId same and not null. otherwise it will create a new one